# Search starting at caret position in Visual Studio 2013 Update 5

Tags: visual-studio-2013, replace, ide, editor

I recently installed update 5 of VS 2013 and came across a very annoying new behaviour: When searching text in the current document, the shortcut F3 no longer starts searching from the position of the caret! Rather, it just skips to the next result in its internal list. Thus, it is no longer possible to skip over a block of a lot of irrelevant matches; you always have to visit each and every match, and always in the exact order how they occur in the file!

Is there any hidden switch to bring back the old and much more intuitive behaviour that makes F3 always start at the caret position?

Comment: I think you're talking about VS 2013 U5, not VS 2015 U5, because such an update does not exist. Also, you've added the "visual-studio-2013" tag. I'm going to change the title.

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed in Update 3 that came out on 6/27/2016.

Comment: Do you have the notes that state that? EDIT: Just saw this was from back in December.

Answer (score 0):

Aaaand... it's back again after these recent updates to "Update 3":

[image]

At least for me. Note that I never noticed this behavior in *any* previous version of VS. For me it started after one of/both these updates.

Comment: Did you try hitting ESC after the first match so the Find dialog goes away, and then continue search with F3?

Comment: Don't think it has anything to do with those update anymore. Suddenly it worked like a charm (next hit after caret). Obviously I somehow have managed to change the "find mode", and then back again, without knowing what triggered the mode changes. As far as I know there are no setting for any "find mode". Maybe internal/undocumented.

Comment: That's my experience too. Usually it works, and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: @digory doo: ESC after the first match doesn't seem to help. But if I close and reopen the document, the "right" mode is back  :)

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour seems to be a bug in Visual Studio. It obviously has been there for many years, since it was seen in VS 2013, 2015, 2017. If it was no bug, but intended and default behaviour, then for sure many more people would have complained about it.

Related description of the same issue:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/27f8971c-63e2-49a1-8f0c-a2efe9890b71/how-to-change-the-search-quotfind-nextquot-functionality?forum=visualstudiogeneral

The user "savehansson" states in a comment to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40762253/2505186 on this question,

> But if I close and reopen the document, the "right" mode is back

I also observe this misbehaviour sometimes, and I fix it by restarting Visual Studio, which implies closing and reopening the document.